# php error: unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR.... trying to install magento using ssh commands to dreamhost

Tags: php, ssh, magento

I am trying to install magento (e-commerce platform)

I am following a tutorial that tells me to run this command using ssh: `./pear mage-setup`

but I'm getting this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in /home/domainname.com/downloader/pearlib/php/System.php on line 400
```

Line 400 is commented in the code snippit from the *system.php* file:

```
   /* Magento fix for set tmp dir in config.ini
     */
    if (class_exists('Maged_Controller',false)) {
        /*line 400 */
        $magedConfig = Maged_Controller::model('Config',true)->load();**
        if ($magedConfig->get('use_custom_permissions_mode') == '1' && 
            $mode = $magedConfig->get('mkdir_mode')) {
            $result = System::mkDir(array('-m' . $mode, $tmpdir));
        } else {
            $result = System::mkDir(array('-p', $tmpdir));
        }

        if (!$result) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help me demystify this error?

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering what the double-stars are on the fifth line:

```
                         #                             here - v
$magedConfig = Maged_Controller::model('Config',true)->load();**
```

---

**Edit:** You are attempting to use "chaining" (`$obj->func()->otherFunc()`) which is only supported in PHP5:

```
$magedConfig = Maged_Controller::model('Config',true)->load();
```

Change the line to this:

```
$magedConfig = Maged_Controller::model('Config',true);
$magedConfig = $magedConfig->load();
```

Your other option is to upgrade to PHP 5, but at this point in the game, it might break your code.

Comment: oops... that was my attempt to comment that line for the purpose of the question... they are not actually in the file

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I changed the code as per your suggestion, and there are other errors happening. 

Also, my dreamhost accound says that i'm using php5-fastCGI. Is this ok? Is there something else that I should do to make sure i'm running PHP5?

Comment: If you can install Magento you're running PHP 5.  Magento won't run on anything below 5.2

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you meet the following requirements:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/system-requirements

Magento only runs on php 5.2.x, not 5.3.
Also make sure the extensions listed on the requirements page are enabled.

Might be different for you, but I can check the php version using

```
php -v
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `./mage mage-setup` instead of `./pear mage-setup`.

Answer (score 0):

The following instruction solved this issue for me:-

> **Solution:**
>
> In the directory that your magento installation is in
>
> nano pear
>
> after the first two lines paste
>
> MAGE_PEAR_PHP_BIN=/usr/local/bin/php5;
>   export MAGE_PEAR_PHP_BIN
>
> ctrl + o -> to save
>   ctrl + x -> to exit

The above solution is about editing file named '**pear**' present in your Magento root folder through terminal. If you have FTP access then you can simply edit the file '**pear**' by adding the following lines at the beginning:-

> MAGE_PEAR_PHP_BIN=/usr/local/bin/php5;
>   export MAGE_PEAR_PHP_BIN

Source: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewreply/222042/